# Conditions and while loop not working properly py(tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter

im making a *Guess the number* game but i have a problem:The user must guess a certain number, and if it exceeds that, the game ends and the user's status is determined,So I created a variable named sam and did this

```
sam = 0
```

And then I made a loop with while and said:

```
while sam < 10:
```

And then, every wrong guess will be added to sam, but the problem is that if you do something wrong, this will happen:

```
>>12 is lower
>>12 is lower
>>12 is lower
>>12 is lower
>>12 is lower
>>12 is lower
>>12 is lower
>>12 is lower
>>12 is lower
>>12 is lower
>>you lose
```

That is, it repeats a condition until sam exceeds 10
And I don't know what to do,
my code:

```
from tkinter import * 
sam = 0
def get_1():
    global correct
    correct = int(player1.get())
    player1.pack_forget()
    sumbit.pack_forget()
def Guess():
    global sam
    a = int(player_2.get())
    while sam < 10:
        if a == correct:
            break
        elif a > correct:
            print(a,"is higher")
            sam += 1 
        elif a < correct:
            print(a,"is lower")
            sam += 1
    if a == correct:
        print("you win")
    else:
        print("you lose")
app = Tk()
player1 = Entry(app,font=20)
app.minsize(300,300)
player1.pack()
player_2 = Entry(app,font=20)
player_2.pack()
sumbit = Button(app,font=10,text="player 1 sumbit",command=get_1)
sumbit.pack()
guss = Button(app,text="player 2  guess number",font=20,command=Guess)
guss.pack()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Well, there is no place inside the `while sam < 10:` loop that `a` is changed, so what do you expect, other than it running through the loop 10 times with the same value for `a`.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, but if a is inside the loop, it still has the same problem

Comment: Your button press starts the `Guess` function and inside `Guess` you are checking 10 times whether the guessed number is correct. Probably you want to check only once and then wait for the next button press, so looping inside `Guess` does not seem correct.

Comment: I understand now, do you have a solution in mind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing GUI programs requires a different mindset than writing non-GUI programs. A loop like the one you created is not appropriate for a GUI. The way GUIs work is that you define functions to be called in response to events, and then the event manager (`mainloop`) is a loop tht waits for events and then dispatches them to the handlers.

So, in your case `Guess` should only handle a single guess and not try to loop over a range of guesses. It can keep a global counter for the number of guesses, and update it each time `Guess` is called.

It might look something like this:

```
def Guess():
    global guesses
    global sam
    a = int(player_2.get())
    player_2.delete(0, "end")

    guesses += 1

    if a == correct:
        print("you win")

    elif guesses == 10:
        print("you lose")

    elif a > correct:
        print(a,"is higher")

    elif a < correct:
        print(a,"is lower")
```

You need to initialize `guesses` to zero when player 1 submits the value, since that designates the start of the game.

```
def get_1():
    global correct
    global guesses
    correct = int(player1.get())
    guesses = 0
    player1.pack_forget()
    sumbit.pack_forget()
```